# how to refer xsd schemalocation inside a jar file?

Tags: xml, jar, xsd

I have a xml schema (xsd) file which is inside a jar file that will be included in the runtime class path. In my Wsdl i need to import the schema by giving location inside the jar file.

I try to use XML catalog but the server i use (websphere) does not resolve xml catalog reference.

Comment: Do you mean the use of XML Catalog standard?

Answer (score 5):

We were facing a similar issue where the JAR containing the XSD was getting added to the classpath and we had to refer to it from WSDL using schemaLocation.
Our project was maven based, so we used the unpack goal of maven-dependency-plugin to download the file to the resources folder before compilation.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>group</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                    <version>${version}</version>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>ToDownload.xsd</includes>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

This results in the xsd getting downloaded to the resources directory in a folder named xsd.
In WSDL `schemaLocation="xsd/ToDownload.xsd".`
This ensures that during compilation the WSDL will refer to the XSD which has been downloaded and locally available.

Comment: As a spare note for future readers: I didn't manage to include a single .xsd file using the syntax above, but when I used `<includes>**/*.xsd</includes>` I've got all the `.xsd` files. That's what I actually wanted, so I didn't go further with investigation, but for some reasons I couldn't download a single file with the above (the output directory was created but no file was downloaded). Btw thanks Utsab for the answer, it was very helpful! +1

Answer (score 4):

Any file contained in a jar-file has its own URL.
For instance, if your jar-file absolute pathname (on Windows):

```
C:\project\jars\somestuff.jar
```

and the pathname of your schema contained in that jar (relative to the jar's root):

```
/xml/schemas/myschema.xsd
```

then the complete URL to the schema file will be this:

```
jar:file:/C:/project/jars/somestuff.jar!/xml/schemas/myschema.xsd
```

Also, if your XML schema contains references to other schemas also found in that jar,
you may use relative pathnames (relative to the given schema).

For example, suppose the `myschema.xsd` imports another schema found in that jar:

```
/xml/schemas/general/types.xsd
```

Then, the `<xs:import>` element may be specified like this:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.company.org/general/types"
           schemaLocation="general/types.xsd"/>
```

which will cause `types.xsd` to be loaded from the same jar-file.

Comment: If my answer isn't OK, then the only valid answer would be about using XML catalog (or any other entity resolver) in that particular system. But exactly this is mentioned as a failure in the question itself! So, it seems the whole question is wrongly formulated then....

Comment: this is OS dependent

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the schema as a file. You need access it as a stream.

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xml/schemas/general/types.xsd"))));
```